# How to bind previous and next history keys to control j and k in bash?

Tags: bash

I've been trying to figure out a way to bind previous-history to **Control k** and next history to **Control j** in bash. I am aware that there are already bindings like **Control p** **and n** for these commands but the thing is I have gotten used to **Control k and j**. I binded them when I was using vim in zsh.

I now need to ssh into a server (which uses bash) for a project and would like to have the same key bindings. I have tried to include these commands in my .inputrc:

```
"C-k": previous-history
"C-j": next-history
```

However it is showing this error when the file is loaded on login.

```
-bash: C-k:: command not found
-bash: C-j:: command not found
```

Besides **C-k and C-j** I also tried using **^k and ^j** as well but it did not work.

Some context: I use a Macbook and these were the bindings that worked for zsh:

```
# For Control k and j
bindkey '^k' up-line-or-history
bindkey '^j' down-line-or-history
```

UPDATE: Also I added . ~/.inputrc in my .bash_profile for it to run during ssh login.

Comment: In `~/.inputrc`, it should be `"\C-k"` and `"\C-j"` (backslash!) – this being said, maybe you want [vi mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-vi-Mode)? This binds `j` and `k` to next/previous command in command mode.

Comment: I think that `Control-k: previous-history` may work as well (without any quote)

Comment: Also, the error message makes me think you're trying to run `~/.inputrc` as a Bash script?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I just tried using the backslash, the same error appears. And yes, I had to add . ~/.inputrc to my bash_profile for .inputrc to run on ssh login.

Comment: You can't do that because it's not a Bash script. It should be read automatically by any interactive Bash session.

Comment: @BenjaminW. OMG I removed it from .bash_profile and used the backslash version \C-k  and \C-p and it worked. Thank You! Post your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Readline init file, `~/.inputrc`, there are two ways to use keybindings (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax)):

- Keynames:

  ```
  Control-k: previous-history
  Control-j: next-history
  ```
- A *keyseq*: this has to be placed in double quotes and recognizes some GNU Emacs style escapes, notably `\C` for Ctrl:

  ```
  "\C-k": previous-history
  "\C-j": next-history
  ```

Also, you can't treat `~/.inputrc` as a Bash script (like sourcing it from a shell initialization file); it is read by whichever program uses the Readline library – Bash, in your case.

You can reload it with [`re-read-init-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-re_002dread_002dinit_002dfile-_0028C_002dx-C_002dr_0029), which is bound to `C-x C-r` by default.